# Capturing an element text in Webdriver and printing it to the command line?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I have various Webdriver scripts that launch a browser, log in to our site and start a transaction, then quits.

My issue is that I would like to `capture` the transaction number and `print` it to the command line after the browser quits.

Is there a way to capture the transaction ID element (`id="TransactionId"`) and then after the browser quits print the `ID` to the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do in **Java**, to get the innerHTML/text of any element. Probably you can replicate the same using ruby:

`String transaction = driver.findElement(By.id("TransactionId")).getText();`

You can get the required text from **transaction** now.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby

Syntax to retrieve attribute values:

```
puts @driver.find_element(:locatorType, "value").attribute("id")
```

example:

```
puts @driver.find_element(:id, "gbqfq").attribute("class")
```

---

Here is the snippet to retrive text:

```
puts @driver.find_element(:id, "TransactionId").text
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the transaction id in a file also. But as per your need you can

```
String str = driver.findElement(By.id("TransactionId")).getText();
```

and return this value from your pageobject method and save it in a local test variable. And after driver.quit log it in console.